# Change ServerAddress of VPN connection

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn

I have a point-to-site VPN connection configured on 30+ client machines and I just had to change the VPN  gateway's address. Of course, that means I have to reconfigure all of the client machines. Rather than do it manually, I was hoping I could create some kind of program or script that I could run which would update things automatically. The *only* thing I need to change is the server address, everything else should stay the same.

I came across these PowerShell commands [Get-VpnConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/get-vpnconnection) and [Set-VpnConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/set-vpnconnection). I can successfully retreive the created VPN connection using this command:

```
Get-VpnConnection MyConnectionName -AllUserConnection
```

So I tried using the `Set` variant:

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name MyConnectionName -ServerAddress NewServerAddress -AllUserConnection
```

But this simply returns and does nothing. No error, no effect. Checking the server address with rasphone shows that the old address is still being used.

I can also do this:

```
$connection = Get-VpnConnection MyConnectionName -AllUserConnection
$connection.ServerName = NewServerAddress
```

This also doesn't do anything, since I'm pretty sure I'm just updating a variable and not "committing" it.

So how can I update the server address? It doesn't even have to be PowerShell, that was just the best option I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a .NET application using [DotRas](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotras).

If anyone's interested, here's the code:

```
Public Const EntryName As String = "VPNEntryNAme"
Public Const NewAddress As String = "NewVPNAddress"

Private Sub B_Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_Update.Click
    Using pbk As New RasPhoneBook()
        pbk.Open(RasPhoneBook.GetPhoneBookPath(RasPhoneBookType.AllUsers))

        Dim VPN = pbk.Entries.Where(Function(Entry) Entry.Name = EntryName).FirstOrDefault

        If VPN Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("VPN not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        VPN.PhoneNumber = NewAddress

        VPN.Update()
    End Using

    Dim cn = RasConnection.GetActiveConnections.Where(Function(c) c.EntryName = EntryName).FirstOrDefault

    If cn IsNot Nothing Then
        cn.HangUp()
    End If

    MsgBox("The VPN has now been successfully updated")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On my side, everything worked fine when I use

```
Set-VpnConnection -Name MyConnectionName -ServerAddress = "x.x.x.x"
```

Maybe you can try to remove the old one and a new one

```
$Connection = Get-VpnConnection -Name MyConnectionName

Remove-VpnConnection -Name MyConnectionName -Force

$Connection.ServerAddress = "x.x.x.x"

$Connection | Add-VpnConnection
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do `$Connection | Add-VpnConnection`, but, unfortunately, neither of these are working for me. `Set-VpnConnection` doesn't update the server address for me. `$Connection | Add-VpnConnection` *does* update the address, but it also loses some of the other settings, such as "PPP Settings" and the preferred and alternate DNS server addresses.

Comment: How this vpn connection has originally been setup ? GPO, Intune,..